# Search on graphs, finding the best way for more than one driving object

Tags: graph-theory, artificial-intelligence, searching

I know about algorithms like A*, Breadth-First, Depth-First , and so on. These algorithms are based on a very bad assumption which makes them not working on actual situations.  I give you an example :

Imagine a city. We have a graph of the city like $G$. Two drivers from one hotel are taking tourists to a beach.  Assume that the cars start the way from the same point.  If you choose DFS, for example, These cars are gonna move exactly on the same directions.  Nothing about an accident is mentioned!

I don't want to make the problem so hard. Assume that you have a simple graph. Now, Instead of just $1$ object, You have many objects like $O_1,O_2,\dots,O_n$ and each of these objects have their own destination. You have the graph of the city. So, you know their starting point and also the destination.  How do you find a way for each of these objects, So that no two objects collide?

Note : The answers like making a delay is not acceptable if you say "Make a priority queue and there would be just $1$ car in the streets at each moment".  Because that won't happen in actual world.

Thanks in advance.